# Create local Word document from template in Sharepoint

Tags: word

We have our company-wide Word templates in Sharepoint as the source of truth and so they can be accessed by everyone in different physical locations. There are often times when someone needs to make a new Word document using these templates but doesn't want to store this document in Sharepoint. I can't figure out a smooth way to enable this.

What I've tried:

1. Add the template to the "New" button in the Document Library in Sharepoint. The problem with this method is it saves the new document into the Document Library by default, so the user needs to do File > Save As > Save a Copy, find the downloaded copy and move it to where they actually wanted it in their local system, go up a level back to the Document Library in Sharepoint, and delete the document that was automatically saved in the Document Library.
2. Open the template directly in Sharepoint with the option "Open in App" to open it in the Desktop Word application. The problem with this method is you're now editing that template rather than creating a new document based on it. The user then needs to do File > Save As and choose a local place to save the document, otherwise risk modifying the template and/or losing their document if they assume Autosave will work immediately.
3. Create a desktop shortcut to the template in Sharepoint. I couldn't get this to work at all. Opening the shortcut opens a Print dialog window, not even opening the Template in Sharepoint as I expected. That's probably a problem with my computer, but this still seemed like an unlikely solution.
4. Open Word locally and choose Open > Sites > find the template in Sharepoint. Like with #2, you're now editing the template instead of creating a new document.

Comment: Is using Power Apps and Power Automate an option? There are premium connectors you can use to create documents from a word template and using Power Automate you could create the file in different locations, send it via email etc.

Comment: Have you gotten an answer? I have the same issue. I was also trying to attach current Word documents to the template stored on SharePoint, so I can save changes to styles, etc. I could not figure out that, either.